# Can't decrypt Forge-encrypted data

Tags: java, node.js, openssl, rsa, pkcs#1

I use this to create a private key and encrypt:

```
var forge = require('node-forge');
var fs = require('fs');

var bytes = forge.random.getBytesSync(16);
console.log("random plaintext", forge.util.bytesToHex(bytes));
var keypair = forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair({bits: 2048, e: 17});
var encrypted = keypair.publicKey.encrypt(bytes, 'RSA-OAEP', {
  md: forge.md.sha256.create(),
  mgf1: {
    md: forge.md.sha1.create()
  }
});

console.log("ciphertext", forge.util.bytesToHex(encrypted));
fs.writeFileSync('ciphertext', encrypted);

var pem = forge.pki.privateKeyToPem(keypair.privateKey);
fs.writeFileSync('prikey.pem', pem);
console.log("private key", forge.util.bytesToHex(pem));
```

I then try decrypting using either:

```
public class CryptoTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(new FileReader("/tmp/prikey.pem"));
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        JcaPEMKeyConverter   converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
        KeyPair kp = converter.getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) parser.readObject());
        RSAPublicKey pubkey = (RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privkey = (RSAPrivateKey) kp.getPrivate();

        byte[] ct = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/ciphertext"));

        Cipher oaepFromInit = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
        OAEPParameterSpec oaepParams = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"), PSpecified.DEFAULT);
        oaepFromInit.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privkey, oaepParams);
        byte[] pt = oaepFromInit.doFinal(ct);
    }

}
```

or

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey prikey.pem -oaep -in ciphertext -out plaintext
```

The Java code throws the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1966)
    at cryptotest.CryptoTest.main(CryptoTest.java:47)
```

and OpenSSL says:

```
RSA operation error
140258189264528:error:0406506C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len:rsa_eay.c:518:
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You failed to convert from hex to binary on the java side.

Comment: @JamesKPolk why would the data be hex'ed? it was only hex in the console output

Comment: oh, I missed that, sorry. For some reason your `ct` array is too long. I don't really know forge so I can't be sure what's going on.

Comment: Try this: `fs.writeFileSync('ciphertext', encrypted, {encoding: 'binary'});`

Comment: @stdob-- that works, could you post an answer? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to keep the coded message in the binary encoding:

`fs.writeFileSync('ciphertext', encrypted, {encoding: 'binary'});`

Comment: Running the script of the question, fixed as above, then `$ openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey prikey.pem -oaep -in ciphertext -out plaintext`, I have the error message:

    RSA operation error
    140004996825536:error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error:../crypto/rsa/rsa_oaep.c:245:
    140004996825536:error:04065072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:padding check failed:../crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:485:

OpenSSL 1.1.1
node-forge:  "version": "0.10.0"