# Getting Error: Encrypted message length is invalid. when trying to decrypt using node-forge

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

I am using powershell to encrypt text and decrypt it using node-forge library in nodejs.

Powershell code

```
function Encrypt-Asymmetric {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.String])]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.String]
        $ClearText,

        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf })]
        [System.String]
        $PublicKeyFilePath,

        [Parameter(Position=2)]
        [System.String]
        $OutputFilePath
    )

    $rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
    $rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo((Get-Content $PublicKeyFilePath -Raw))

    $encryptedBytes = $rsa.Encrypt([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ClearText), $true)
    $encryptedBase64String = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($encryptedBytes)

    if ($OutputFilePath) {
        $encryptedBase64String | Set-Content -Path $OutputFilePath
    }

    return $encryptedBase64String
}

$clearText = "thisisasecret"
$publicKeyFilePath = "public1.pem"
$outputFilePath = "encrypted.txt"

$encryptedString = Encrypt-Asymmetric -ClearText $clearText -PublicKeyFilePath $publicKeyFilePath -OutputFilePath $outputFilePath
Write-Output "Encrypted: $encryptedString"
```

And decrypt code is

```
const forge = require('node-forge');
const fs = require('fs');

function decryptAsymmetric(encryptedString, privateKeyFilePath) {
    const privateKeyPem = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyFilePath, 'utf8');
    const privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(privateKeyPem);

    const encryptedBytes = forge.util.decode64(encryptedString);
    const decryptedBytes = privateKey.decrypt(encryptedBytes, 'RSA-OAEP', {
        md: forge.md.sha256.create(),
        mgf1: {
            md: forge.md.sha256.create()
        }
    });

    return decryptedBytes.toString();
}

const encryptedString =
    "IdnKfQ3tPZH/5AdYbqhsMzvRbW6/VQgGjvmJYtuQz/VT5nxlfVIDVTXKayIMDhnCtLvprODAOFg5GBhPUwEUtzuO4H7T6wzPu84Pnev4UyNC/w0cmnPBixwRggyVQpOvso1rKeTfD5wNcSTtQ4KIaQScSUC/+U5oAldhbjI5S1Y="
    //fs.readFileSync('encrypted.txt', 'utf8')

const privateKeyFilePath = 'private1.key';

const decryptedText = decryptAsymmetric(encryptedString, privateKeyFilePath);
console.log('Decrypted:', decryptedText);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Encrypted message length is invalid.
```

I am testing in my local environment, running the powershell code to encrypt and copy pasting the value from terminal to nodejs code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't decrypt Forge-encrypted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060372/cant-decrypt-forge-encrypted-data)

Comment: @ayrusme nope it doesn't.